# Retrieving PSID from messaging_optins

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger

I'm a new developer building a facebook messenger chatbot using node.js and Microsoft's BotFramework. I've got my chatbot up and running nicely and I'm now trying to personalise the welcome message with the user's first name.

I have a welcome message set up when a user clicks the "Get Started" button and I believe I should be able to retrieve the PSID using messaging_optins.

If so, I've got a a function that processes the Facebook payload in onEvent from the EventActivity.Value:
[image]

This cycles through some if/else statements to detect whether the Facebook payload is a Postback, Optin or Quick Reply:
[image]

If an Optin is detected it then prints "Optin message received" to the console:
[image]

The problem I'm finding is that my code isn't detecting the Optin message and so I'm not then able to write any code to extract the PSID to use to personalise my welcome message.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve solved this as I found from the documentation [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjG3Z7cvMbjAhVgThUIHT8bAaUQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fmessenger-platform%2Freference%2Fwebhook-events%2Fmessaging_postbacks%2F&usg=AOvVaw3TTU1HvKKCWrybP6CPGQsb) that it’s `messaging_postback` that are sent when 'Get Started' is clicked.